# Swift Message Text Area

Tags: swift, swift2

I am creating a new app and I want to add message area like:

[image]

When user click the text area keyboard will shown and user start writing message right button will be send button and text area with will be grow like:

[image]

What is the easy way to do it?

I hava a idea to do it but I think it is not the the best way. I am thinking to solve it programmaticly. In viewLoad I will create button and text area programmaticly then when user starts writing I will create them again.

Comment: In addition to textfield delegates, you need to handle keyboard as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [official apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) you can work with `UITextField` delegate methods to intercept the differents states.

For example you can use [textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidBeginEditing:) to handle the moment when the user start to edit. Here , you can handle constraints to enlarge your textField (pay attention, you must working with constraints if you use autolayout, dont make frame modifications):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    //
    // hide photo button
    // change mic button to send button
    self.textFieldTrailingConstraint.constant = 10.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

After that you can handle the other delegates:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool { 
  textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

where you can repeat your animation or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend to solve this in code. Loading the view you'll have to create all buttons and if the user starts writing you should recreate some of the buttons. But keep in Mind that you have to ensure, that the Textfield is the same instance or that you have to resign the responder to it by code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to textfield delegates, you need to handle keyboard as well:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillAppear:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillDisappear:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(true)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)}

func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){

var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

var contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
self.commentField.frame = messageFrame}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
var userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.25)
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
UIView.commitAnimations()

self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero

var messageFrame:CGRect = self.commentField.frame
messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
self.commentField.frame = messageFrame}
```